# Animating List Item repositioning during List Resize using just CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have recently taken interest in HTML5 UI design/development

i'm working on a small project where i am trying to animate the repositioning of my list Items (li) when the size of the (ul) changes...

These list items float to the left and overflows in a grid fashion every time the container holding the list changes its size, the list item re-orders just to fill the available space.(This happens by default).

My question is how do i apply CSS3 in such a way that a transition animation kicks in during the change making each element beautifully slide into its new position.

This is the UI i am working on. [plunkr code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3v5R1bTA7Wl4cEYmEFd).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please localize the problem so that we can help you more quickly and with more precision

Comment: Sorry i was under the impressionthe plunkr link would clearly state what i am trying to achieve. All i just want to know is why my current code isnt animating. 

1. Do i put the transition code on each list item?
2. Will a change in the container width (by changing the left property) trigger the transition. i just dont understand why the code isnt working.